# Why doesn't it recognized the module? (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, module, package

I tried to create a package but I got that error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyMainPackage'
```

This is my folders:

**MyMainPackage**

__ pycache __ (folder)

SubPackage (folder)

__ intit __.py

some_main_script.py

```
def report_main():
print("Hey I'm in some_main_script in main package.")
```

**SubPackage**

__ pycache __ (folder)

__ init __.py

mysubscripts.py

```
def sub_report():
print("Hey I'm function inside mysubscript")
```

**NOTE: "MyMainPackage" is one of the sub_folders that I have for my "Programing" folder. another sub_folder I have called "Python Project", that inside her there's that file:**

```
from MyMainPackage import some_main_script
from MyMainPackage.SubPackage import mysubscript

some_main_script.report_main()

mysubscript.sub_report()
```

When I ran the file, I got the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/yoavo/Desktop/Programing/Python Projects/myprogram.py", line 1, in <module>
from MyMainPackage import some_main_script
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyMainPackage'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your myprogram.py file to the root of Programming folder So you have such a structure like this. Python looks for the module from the root folder of your current script.

```
Programming
|
|__myprogram.py
|
|__MyMainPackage
```

Comment: That is the case, but I'd need to do that from the "Python Projects" folder.

Comment: If you want it to run from the Python Projects folder use 
`from ..MyMainPackage import some_main_script`. The .. tells python to move up one folder and look for the module

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that you haven't either name your main package exactly what you are calling in your mainprogram. Be aware of the spaces and bars for the naming of your mainpackage.